# Combining two ffmpeg fillters or commands into single command

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to combine two ffmpeg commands to single ffmpeg command. I want to apply a vintage effect and a watermark on a video.

Please help me in creating a single ffmpeg command.

Comment: Please show the exact commands you're trying to combine.

Answer (score 20):

It's very simple. If you have a single filter working on one video stream:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "scale=-1:480" output
```

… and you want to add a second filter, then all you have to do is add it with a comma:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter:v "scale=-1:480, fps=fps=30" output
```

This will generate a chain of filters. You don't need to specify input and output here, since it'll just take the input file's video stream.

---

If on the other hand you have a complex filtergraph (i.e. one that uses multiple chains and multiple inputs/outputs) you have to pipe the filterchain output to the next filterchain's input, separate the chains by a semicolon (`;`), and then map the overall filter output to the output file:

```
ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay [ol]; \
[ol] scale=-1:480 [outv]" -map "[outv]" output
```

Of course, you can use as many chains and filters you want. Read the [filtergraph documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description) for more info. There are tons of examples on how to combine filters.

Comment: Command for Add silence:  

 ./ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex 'aevalsrc=0:d=5[silence];aevalsrc=0:d=5[silence2];[silence][0:a][silence2] concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out]' -map [out] -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 output.mp3

 Command for Trimm:

  ./ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -ss 00:00:15.673 -t 00:01:08.545 -vn -codec:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 128k -map a -af afade=t=in:st=15:d=0,afade=t=out:st=84:d=0,volume=1 output.mp3 , Can you help me to merge these command to a single one

Comment: @LinsLouis Please ask a new question and show what you have already tried.